# rbuildfiles returns all external dependencies in WORKSPACE

Tags: bazel

I have a .bzl file in the same directory as WORKSPACE. This .bzl file is loaded by the WORKSPACE and one other file in the source tree. 

`bazel query --universe_scope=//... --order_output=no 'rbuildfiles(variables.bzl)'`

prints the paths of the two files I would expect, but also references to about 200 other files which are all external dependencies and cannot possibly depend on variables.bzl

for example:

    `@pypi__futures_3_2_0//:BUILD
    @pypi__grpcio_1_14_1//:BUILD
    @eigen//:BUILD.bazel
    @io_bazel_rules_go//go/private:BUILD.bazel`

Assuming I am doing something incorrectly and that this is not a bug. Any expertise would be greatly appreciated. How can I use rbuilddeps to return /only/ the files which load variables.bzl?

Answer (score 1):

The `WORKSPACE` file of the main repo can arbitrarily affect external repositories. So, `rbuildfiles` is showing you because changes to `variables.bzl` could in fact affect all those external `BUILD` files indirectly through `WORKSPACE`.

If you don't actually want to see the BUILD files in external repositories, you could intersect the result of `rbuildfiles` with `//...`.